# MongoDB PHP function InsertMany() is not working

Tags: php, mongodb, error-handling, mongodb-query

I am facing problem in MongoDB with PHP, I am using MongoDB InsertMany() function with the below code--

```
$document = array(array( 
          "title" => $_POST['title'], 
          "description" => $_POST['description'], 
          "likes" => $_POST['likes'],
          "writenby" => $_POST['writtenby'],
          "url" => $_POST['urllnk'],
        ), array("label1"=>"1","label2"=>"2"),  array("label3"=>"3","label4"=>"4"));

        $collection->insertMany($document);
```

I tried to insert data but the code is not working.

Thanks

Comment: Why are these 3 sets not equal in column names? Do you have a column name called `label1`? `label3`? `label4`? Look here what the method really does https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/pull/3/commits/af72fa5f666b74c0f77fb4e7712b87759f1a11ec

Comment: Thanks. Got the solution

Comment: I want to know why my above code will not work. whats wrong with above code.

Comment: The above works fine with my set up. Is there a way you can add the rest of the code ?

Comment: I have received all the value from the form post event and I want to save it in my MongoDB with some extra documents. it's a core PHP part but I am not able to do that. Below code is not working. I just want to know what is the actual problem.

Comment: if((count($_POST)>0) && ($_POST['submit']=='Save Details') && ($_POST['hdnid']==''))
{ array(array( 
         "title" => $_POST['title'], 
         "description" => $_POST['description'], 
          "likes" => $_POST['likes'],
          "writenby" => $_POST['writtenby'],
          "url" => $_POST['urllnk'],
        ), array("title"=>"The books","description"=>"Content goes here", "likes"=>"102","writenby"=>"Author","URL"=>"https://openlibrary.org/"),  array("title"=>"My Thoughts","description"=>"Content goes here", "likes"=>"101","writenby"=>"Author","URL"=>"https://openlibrary.org/"));

Comment: $collection->insert($document);
header("location:index.php"); }

Comment: Can you add the code where you are getting mongo database and collection ?

Comment: //Below is MongoDB connection --                                                                            

   $m = new MongoClient();


   $db = $m->mydb;
    

   $collection = $db->createCollection("mycol");                                                    
                                                                                                     
    $collection = $db->mycol;